# How to use lookahead and $ with Regex

Tags: regex, zapier

I am trying to get the name of the resource, I will share with you the [regexr url](http://regexr.com/676v5)

My actual regular expression: `([^/]+)(?=\..*)`

My example: `https://res-3.cloudinary.com/ngxcoder/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto/v1/blog-images/5oonz9.jpg`

I'm trying to get just `5oonz9`

I tried to include $, but I don't know why it doesn't work

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
^.+\/(.+)\..+$
```

- `^.+` - From the start, match as many characters as possible
- `\/` - Match a literal `/`.
- `(.+)` - Match one or more characters and capture them in a group
- `\.` - Match a literal `.`
- `.+$` - Match one or more characters at the end of the string (the extension)

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/Edk8Zc/1).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a capture group, just a match:

```
(?<=\/)[^\/.]+(?=\.[^\/.]+$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xg6vbM/1)

We can write the expression in *free-spacing* mode to make it self-documenting:

```
(?<=      # begin a negative lookbehind
  \/      # match '/'
)         # end negative lookbehind
[^\]+     # match one or more characters other than '/'
(?=       # begin a positive lookahead
  \.      # match '.'
  [^\/]+  # match one or more characters other than '/'
  $       # match end of string
)         # end the positive lookahead
```

---

You should not use a regex for this, however, as Python provides `os.path`:

```
import os
```

```
str = 'https://res-3.cloudinary.com/ngxcoder/image/'\
      'upload/f_auto,q_auto/v1/blog-images/5oonz9.jpg'
base = os.path.basename(str)
print(os.path.splitext(base)[0])
  #=> "5oonz9"
```

Here `base #=> "5oonz9.jpg"`.

[See it in action](https://tio.run/##NY1BCsIwEEX3OUV3bUEzSnGh4ElEJG1jGkkyYzKV1svHtuDq8/gPHs08YGhytp4wcoFJiMSxuBblwEzpAhB12jeyczj2Nqg4yw49BDN12OsI1iujYSSHqofnQ42Mu/c28DlC69DsNyXBCTF8z/JFphStSnppYJKkeJArBuV1taRrQdEGrv5fImdZT1ytUn073Gshcv4B)

[Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways:

Couple below using python:

#using regexp:

```
>>> file_name='https://res-3.cloudinary.com/ngxcoder/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto/v1/blog-images/5oonz9.jpg'
>>> regexpr = r".*/([^\/]+).jpg$"
>>> re.match(regexpr, file_name).group(1)
'5oonz9'
>>>
```

#to get any file name:

```
>>> regexpr = r".*/([^\/]+)$"
>>> re.match(regexpr, file_name).group(1)
'5oonz9.jpg'
```

#if interested, here is one using split & take last

```
>>> (file_name.split("/")[-1]).split(".")[0]
'5oonz9'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a more straightforward solution thanks to other answers:

```
([^\/]+)(?=\.[^\/.]+$)
```

Explanation:

`([^\/]+)` don't match 1 or more '/'

`(?=\.)` look ahead for '.'

`[^\/.]+` don't match 1 or more '/' and '.' (This was the key!!)

`$` end of the string